# Ubercart: has an order been paid?

Tags: ubercart, commerce

Are there any good Ubercart hooks or other API features so I can learn about whether my Ubercart orders have been paid at all?

Basically all I need is a function that would tell me if an order invoice has been paid-in-full or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use
[uc_payment_balance()](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/uc_payment_balance) function to know how much the customer still owes to you.

```
  uc_payment_balance($order)
```

where $order - the order object

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thanks for the fast/great answer.

Comment: Can this be reflected on the Printable Invoice to show that it's been paid?

Comment: Yes you can reflect it on the invoice